# WordPress development site on sub-domain going to wrong domain

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set up a development site on the sub-domain development.warriorsliveon.org of warriorsliveon.org.

This is a WordPress site and I copied the plug-ins, themes, and upload folders to the new WordPress installation on the sub-domain. I also copied the database from warriorsliveon.org, did a find and replace of warriorsliveon.org to development.warriorsliveon.org.

When I go to the site , http://development.warriorsliveon.org. it either switches automatically to the follow address, or other times, lets me log into WordPress, but then goes to this address.

http://development.development.www.development.development.warriorsliveon.org/

Anyone have any ideas where I should look to resolve this issue?

I'm happy to post any code, just not sure at this point what would be useful. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you say "did a find and replace of warriorsliveon.org to development.warriorsliveon.org" - how did you go about doing this?

Comment: I opened the file in in a text editor, first did a find and replace of http://www.warriorsliveon.org to http://www.development.warriorsliveon.org

Comment: After which, I did another of warriorsliveon.org to development.warriorsliveon.org

Comment: Its not an answer to your question, but I can suggest a possible solution - especially as you don't seem to have much experience with WP (you need to update the database, not just text files). I'd suggest abandoning the current copy and starting again with a fresh copy using the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). Its incredibly easy to use - it on the website you want to copy and build an archive of that site that you can copy to and install on another domain. It will handle all the domain changes etc so you don't have any of the issues you're experiencing now.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Domain Name that your Wordpress installation runs under is more complicated than just editing one or two files. The best approach is to use a tool like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

If you download this free tool and upload to your server then it does a batch find-and-replace across every single table in your Wordpress database.

So, for example, replace http://www.warriorsliveon.org with http://development.warriorsliveon.org

You can do a dry run and it will show you all the replaces that it will make. Once you're happy then click the "live run" button and all the changes are made.

I use this tool all the time when I am moving a site from my local machine to the live server. I also use the exact same approach when migrating a site from http to https

Comment: Okay. I'll give that a go. Thx

Comment: An alternative is to use a "cloning" plugin like the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) - it creates an archive of the entire site and handles all the domain changes - you don't need to worry about doing it yourself. Not to take away from @Chris's solution - is also perfectly viable - but just thought I'd mention it  as an alternative option... especially for the inexperienced user, it doesn't get much simpler than Duplicator. I use it in all the same situations as Chris describes.

Comment: I'll give it a go next time! I'm stuck in my ways and have always used the tool I mentioned. Thanks Fluffy

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you specifically should change! I was just offering an alternative to anyone who might read your answer. You have enough understanding of WP to know what you're doing and to fix it if it goes wrong, but the OP doesn't appear to have the same level of knowledge so I thought Duplicator might be suitable for them as it's one of the easiest I've found. But if you're looking for a change, its worth checking out in my opinion :-)

Comment: For the record. There was nothing wrong with the way I was going about creating the development site. Turns out I just needed to re-export the database again and do only one find and replace. Also had a couple missing files in the theme folder that was producing errors, but I copied over the files from the original site and it solved the problem...though I still have no idea what the cause of the domain change was...  Just the same, thanks for your help everyone...